# Update user data in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Good day everyone, Please I need your help on how to update a user data. I am new to angular and ionic. I have been able to retrieve user id from local storage, and also write a method that out the user new data, the problem I am having is how to update the user with the new data. This is my code below. Thanks.

```
// Update user info
  updateMethod(){

    // Retrieve user Id
    let isUserLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('currentUserId');

    //this output user new info
    this.user = {
      first_name:this.user.first_name,
      last_name: this.user.last_name,
      username: this.user.username,
      email: this.user.email,
      billing: {
        phone: this.user.billing.phone,
        address_1: this.user.billing.address_1,
      }
   };
   console.log('new update', this.user);  
   //update user data
    this.WC.UpdateUser( isUserLoggedIn).then((data)=>{
         console.log('update successful', data);
       });

  }
```

**service.ts**

```
//siteUrl of the wordpress site
  siteUrl:string ='https://example.com';
  apiUrl:string ='';
  woocommercePath:string ='/wp-json/wc/v3/'
  wooPath:string ='/wp-json/wc/v2/'

  // woocommerce generated api keys
  consumerKey:string ='ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  consumerSecret:string ='cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


UpdateUser(userData){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  });

  let usersData = this.JSON_to_URLEncoded(userData);

  this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}customers/${userData}?consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
  console.log('Update users data : ', this.apiUrl);


  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    this.userupdate = this.http.put(this.apiUrl,usersData, {headers});
    this.userupdate.subscribe((responseData) => {
      resolve(responseData);
    });
  });

}
```

Comment: are you having issue with `this.WC.UpdateUser` ? or are you have problem saving to localStorage?

Comment: not having an issue with localStorage/WC.UpdaterUser.  I want to collect data from this.user = {
      first_name:this.user.first_name,
      last_name: this.user.last_name,
      username: this.user.username,
      email: this.user.email,
      billing: {
        phone: this.user.billing.phone,
        address_1: this.user.billing.address_1,
      }
   };  to update this.WC.UpdateUser( isUserLoggedIn).then((data)=>{
         console.log('update successful', data);
       }); but I dont know how to go achieve it.

Comment: why not pass in as a parameter? or save in localStorage and retrieve it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

```
 this.WC.UpdateUser( isUserLoggedIn).then((data)=>{
         console.log('update successful', data);
       });
```

To

```
 this.WC.UpdateUser( isUserLoggedIn, this.user).then((data)=>{
         console.log('update successful', data);
       });
```

And in service file.

FROM

```
UpdateUser(userData){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  });

  let usersData = this.JSON_to_URLEncoded(userData);

  this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}customers/${userData}?consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
  console.log('Update users data : ', this.apiUrl);


  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    this.userupdate = this.http.put(this.apiUrl,usersData, {headers});
    this.userupdate.subscribe((responseData) => {
      resolve(responseData);
    });
  });

}
```

To

```
UpdateUser(id,userData){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders ({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  });

  let usersData = this.JSON_to_URLEncoded(userData);

  this.apiUrl = `${this.siteUrl}${this.woocommercePath}customers/${id}?consumer_key=${this.consumerKey}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
  console.log('Update users data : ', this.apiUrl);


  return new Promise ((resolve) => {
    this.userupdate = this.http.put(this.apiUrl,usersData, {headers});
    this.userupdate.subscribe((responseData) => {
      resolve(responseData);
    });
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without showing your this.WC.updateUser method, no correct suggestion or answer will come.

Please post that first then we can help out.

In simple terms, localStorage.setItem(), JSON.stringify()) will suffice. Then when you want get it out you need to do the reverse.

Comment: I have updated it, with the service page where I wrote the WC.Update method. Thanks

Comment: ok got it.
So you have, the unique_id of the user, he data that you want to update. Now using these 2 objects you can make a POST call to your backend you can easily update the user. Are you having any trouble doing that?

Comment: Adding to it,
rather that wrapping in a new promise you can return a promise from the Observable (since i noticed you are going for Promise based approach than the Observables approach)

`return this.http.put(this.apiUrl, usersData, {headers}).toPromise();`

Then  on the consumer `.then()` method you already have the code.

Comment: If you are beginner try making the update call to the API directly from tools like Postman, Soapui, VSCode Rest client etc. and see if it updates the user and if it does what input does it need to update the user (or for that matter any collection or table)

Good luck.